# Is it possible to amend npm run start to copy a file to another location before running its other functions?

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, git

I am working on a React Native SPA app and having created it using create-react-app, I am working on development at localhost:3000.

I have also created a PHP endpoint but as this server does not support php, I am having to host that on another port and served by WP.local. I know I could use xampp or similar, but I already have Local installed for my WordPress development and want to reduce duplication. For this reason the location of the api folder is at *C:\Users[user]\Local Sites[myApp]\app\public\api*

I'd like to keep all my files in the same folder as I work on them, not least to make updating with git a lot easier. So I thought: why not prepend a copy of my .php endpoints from an /api folder in my app to the working api folder before it goes onto the development build?

So far I have been digging into the */node-modules/react-scripts* folder and trying to figure out if JS security allows file copying, but haven't had much luck, so I wonder if the scripts folder can execute a batch file or shell command to do the copy before calling *react-scripts start*

Would be really grateful if anyone can help me achieve this, or find a better solution...

Comment: You can put any terminal command you want into the `scripts` part of `package.json`, so yes you can use `cp` to copy files before running a build command.

Comment: i think need to create batch script file so you can copy file or remove file also you can use put you command also like `npm start`